Raster reclassification with QGIS
Is it possible to assign a value to each pixel in this image from the legend
which is in *.png format with QGIS?
I have an image whose pixels do not contain the values ​​as shown in the legend. The image contains only pixel color, how do I reclassify it?


Even if possible, it would be a botch. Try finding the original data.
